# covert text into column name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 table say `TAB_A` and `TAB_B`, `TAB_A` contains column names of the `TAB_B`(it not contains all the columns). I need to build SQL query(not PL/SQL) to list the values for each columns like below

```
TAB_A.FIELD      
COLUMN_1
COLUMN_2
COLUMN_3


    TAB_B   
COLUMN_1    COLUMN_2    COLUMN_3   COLUMN_4
1           A           S          100 
2           V           F          200
3                       B          300


Output
FIELD       VALUE
COLUMN_1    1
COLUMN_1    2
COLUMN_1    3
COLUMN_2    A
COLUMN_2    V
COLUMN_3    S
COLUMN_3    F
COLUMN_3    B
```

I tried with several things, all are taking value as text instead of column name.

Comment: Are you building this query "on the fly" to execute it from, say Java or .Net? Or does it need to be a canned and pre-parsed SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select 'column1' as field, column1 as value from t where column1 is not null
union all
select 'column2' as field, column2 as value from t where column2 is not null
union all
select 'column3' as field, column3 as value from t where column3 is not null
union all
select 'column4' as field, column4 as value from t where column3 is not null;
```

This is an "unpivot" operation and `union all` is a reasonable approach when there are not too many columns and the data is not too big.  If you need to choose the columns based on another table, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: TAB_B Count is more than 100 and  I'm unaware of the column names. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the query externally to be parsed and executed, then it is possible. As a pre-parsed SQL statement you can't dynamically compare object names to retrieved values as the parser would have to execute the query to find out if it were valid. OR how would it handle you having a column name in tab_a.field that does not exist as an actual column in tab_b?

That said, if you could do this in two steps you could:

1) Select the list of distinct values from tab_a.field and assemble them into a comma-separated list as a string literal.

2) put that string literal into the correct spot here:
select col_name, val from tab_b
unpivot ( val for col_name in (:your_list_from_step_1))
order by col_name, val

3) Execute it.

But even then, this could only work if all the columns in tab_b had the same basic datatype. How do you expect Oracle to retrieve in a single column a mix of numbers, strings, and dates? return cursors ARE typed.

To resolve that, you'd need to query the data dictionary to find all of the data types of all possible columns in tab_b, and do something like write a view over top to normalize them all to a single datatype (probably varchar2) that could all be returned in a single cursor column.

If you are really going to go down this route - I don't envy you the headaches. But I do guarantee one thing - you won't find a way to merge query metadata pointing to object names into a pre-prepared and pre-parsed query. Oracle's parser matches object names to string literals in your query only - not to dynamically retrieved values.